# C# equivalent of Java's DataOutputStream?

Tags: java, c#, networking, stream, netty

I've done quite a bit of research on the topic and I see that this question is asked quite often, but none of them have the answer that I'm looking for, the most common solution was to use the **BinaryWriter** class that comes with C#, however it doesn't seem to be doing it's job.

For my Server Application I'm using **Netty** a Java Based NIO Networking Library which makes use of DataInput and DataOutput Streams. I have a client that works in java, but it was just for testing purposes and I'm now in the progress of moving it over to C# to put it into my game.

Here's the C# Code in its basic format, just trying to get things working for the time being..

```
Client = new TcpClient ();
try 
{
    Client.Connect (IPAddress.Parse ("127.0.0.1"), PORT);
    Stream = Client.GetStream();
    ClientOutput = new BinaryWriter(Stream);
    ClientInput = new BinaryReader(Stream);

    ClientOutput.Write ((string) "UserIsBob");
    ClientOutput.Write ((string) "MyPassLol");
    ClientOutput.Flush();

}
```

Now, this looks fine; but here's the problem, when using

```
DataInputStream.readUTF()
```

On the Java server, nothing happens; However if I use

```
DataOutputStream.writeUTF(String)
```

From the java client, the server will read it perfectly fine and print it to the console.

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong, but there doesn't seem to be much information on it. The functionality that I require is the following:

- WriteByte(byte)
- WriteBytes(byte[])
- WriteUTF(String)
- WriteInt(int)
- WriteLong(long)
- WriteFloat(float)
- WriteDouble(double)
- WriteBoolean(boolean)

From my understanding you can do all of this in the **BinaryWriter** class by just typecasting, **but it doesn't seem to be picked up by the Java DataInputStream**

After reading the documentary posted by nodakai, I came up with this code:

```
void WriteUTF(string utf) 
{
    short buffer = (short)System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(utf);
    ClientOutput.Write ((short)buffer);
    ClientOutput.Write ((string)utf);
}
```

However, it still doesn't work.

I did a little more looking into it and found that if I used **InputStream.ReadShort()** that I could get the value sent, so the String with the value of "Hello World" would be send like this

```
WriteShort(11)
WriteString("Hello World")
Flush()
```

However, when doing the equivalent in C#, it still doesn't come through, even though it's read on the java side the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read Javadoc carefully?

- [`DataOutputStream.writeUTF()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29)

`DataInputStream.readUTF()` / `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()` use their own encoding scheme.  I don't think .NET `BinaryReader/Writer` can be compatible with them wrt Unicode strings.  However you can manually serialize Unicode strings as a length data followed by a byte sequence.

Comment: I never saw that, but I still don't fully understand how to go about it; From what I understand a `BinaryWriter.Write(((byte[]) new byte[2]) + String);` is what it's talking about, but I don't see this working.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it all working simply because you pointed out the encryption changes.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a C# Conversion of Java's DataInputStream and DataOutputStream you can collect them here.

https://bitbucket.org/CTucker1327/c-datastreams/src

To construct these classes you would pass a BinaryWriter or BinaryReader into the constructor.

To Construct DataOutputStream

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BinaryWriter(Stream));
```

To Construct DataInputStream

```
DataInptuStream in = new DataInputStream(new BinaryReader(Stream));
```

Comment: The link is dead. And I didn't find it with a Google search. Any chance you can update it?

Comment: @NightOwl888 - I'll have to look around for the source on my old PC. There were a few forks around you could look for.

Comment: @Hobbyist - Could you upload the source for DataOutputStream & DataInputStream in c# please?